# Are electrons in a singlet state still electrons?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, quantum-spin

Given that some interactions such as electron capture make the electron "disappear" and the output fermion is a neutrino, I wonder what is the rationale behind saying that in the case of two opposite spin electrons joined in a singlet state, emitting a single spectral line as one would expect from a single object, there are still two particles and not just one until it splits. Is this arbitrary or is there more to it?

Comment: Two electrons don’t form a bound state. Are you talking about helium?

Comment: I was thinking about a single atomic orbital populated by too antiparallel spins electrons. But I might misunderstand a lot of things. Glad to see you btw.